# How does this Javascript code snippet work?

Tags: javascript

I have this code snippet that I need to figure out and I'm not much of a JS programmer.

```
load([
    {x:234, ppi: ppi, center: true, y:150, width:$('.ProductThumbImage img').width(), height: $('.ProductThumbImage img').height(), distance:1, imageurl: $('.ProductThumbImage img').attr('src')}
    ], wall, false);
```

I'm guessing we're calling for a load function and we're giving it an object with a bunch of data, but here is the trick. In all the code for this project, I haven't found the load function's declaration.

I have no idea how this actually works, anyone could explain it to me please?

Update: I wasn't clear. I know what the result of this function running. I have no idea how this could actually work by not having a declaration in the entire project. I searched for it carefully.

Comment: The only explanation is you missed the function declaration...

Comment: "I wasn't clear. I know what the result of this function running. I have no idea how this could actually work by not having a declaration in the entire project. I searched for it carefully."

Comment: There must be a function name `load` with three arguments in your code or you are using some plugin. Please post your entire code if possible.

Comment: It was very clear... this function not being a native one, it has to be defined somewhere. Maybe in some external JS Library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native `load` function, and therefore nobody can help you in explaining what that function could possibly do. Try checking every js file that is being included on the page/app.

Answer (score 1):

The load function is either loaded from another `<script>` tag or generated dynamically. Use your environment debug tools (Firebuf, Chrome Console) to set breakpoint at this line and inspect `load` function in memory from there.